# Single Pass in Memory Indexing

Tags: time-complexity, sorting, information-retrieval

I was reading single pass in memory indexing and had few doubts.

Why is the time complexity of SPIMI O(T) where T are the token.
We know that before writing blocks to Disk, we have to sort dictionary terms. So, why don't we consider log(T) factor of it?

Also, if there is some data in memory then while performing sorting can we sort it in log(n) time if all of the main memory is exhausted?

Comment: Slow down. What exactly are you talking about? Read the question again, and tell me how is anyone supposed to know what your question means?

Comment: @gnasher729 I am talking about the index construction for information retrieval method. Everything else is clear afaik.